# Как вставить admob рекламу (баннером) в PhoneGap приложение?

Tags: javascript, html, phonegap, admob

Здравствуйте! У меня есть вопрос - Как вставить admob рекламу (баннером) в PhoneGap приложение? Пробовал всякие плагины / инструкции и прочее, но у меня так ничего и не вышло. Если есть возможность подробно расписать что куда вписать, буду благодарен.